# Check iCloud Free Space that can be used by App

Tags: ios, swift, icloud-drive

I want to check the free space of iCloud Storage that can be used by my app.

I followed the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/33923859. But From the answer value of `NSFileSize` just returns a value `128`.

How to get free space of iCloud documents